# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence please

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My code is working right except when i enter r1 into the function equation below

```
def u(Substrate):         
    return((u_max*ys[:,0])/(Ks+ys[:,0]))


biomass = ys[:,1]    
u = u(ys[:,0])

def r1(u,biomass):
    r1 = u*biomass*YieldCO2_1
    return r1

r1 = r1(u,biomass)

def F(y,t):    
    Ptot = 710
    Vgas = 2
    D = 0.00826*(273.15+Temp)    
    Cstar_CO2 = KH_CO2 * y[2]
    Cstar_CH4 = KH_CH4 * y[3]
    TG_CO2 = KLa_CO2*(Cstar_CO2-y[0])
    TG_CH4 = KLa_CH4*(Cstar_CH4-y[1])
    Q_CO2 = -D*V*TG_CO2
    Q_CH4 = -D*V*TG_CH4
    Qgas = (Q_CO2+Q_CH4)+Q
    F=np.zeros(4)
    F[0] = Q/V * (CO2_To-y[0]) + TG_CO2 + r1
    F[1] = Q/V * (CH4_Do-y[1]) + TG_CH4 
    F[2] = -Ptot*D*TG_CO2*(V/Vgas)-y[2]*(Qgas/Vgas)
    F[3] = -Ptot*D*TG_CH4*(V/Vgas)-y[3]*(Qgas/Vgas)
    return F 

yinit = np.array([4,3,250,200])             
ts = np.arange(0,4,0.4)  
y = odeint(F,yinit,ts)
```

When r1 is seen in equation F[0] I get the following error:

```
F[0] = Q/V * (CO2_To-y[0]) + TG_CO2 + r1
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
odepack.error: Error occurred while calling the Python function named F
```

However when I do the function without the r1 array, there is no error. so that is why i am assuming something is wrong with putting the r1 array into the function
If anyone could provide input to my problem i would

Comment: Maybe F should be `F = np.zeros((4, len(r1))`

Comment: You are clobbering names all over the place.  E.g `u = u(ys[:,0])`, `r1 = r1(u,biomass)`, using `F` as a variable in a function called `F`.   You should not use variable names that are the same as the function names.  It makes your code difficult to understand and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

`F[0] = expression` expects `expression` to be a number here, not an array. However `Q/V * (CO2_To-y[0]) + TG_CO2 + r1` is an array of `r1` dimensions. To see this, try evaluating the following line:

```
>>> 1 + numpy.array([1,2])
array([2, 3])
```

To get rid of the exception you should covert this expression to a number somehow depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response!                                A number? what i am trying to achieve is the functions are differential equations that vary per time. i am solving for the y values, y[0], y[1], y[2], and y[3].There should be different values of y's for each time variable.

Comment: Yes, but each time you assign a value to `F[0]`, that value must be a scalar.  Apparently the expression you are assigning to `F[0]` is not a scalar.

Comment: @user2199360, `Q/V * (CO2_To-y[0]) + TG_CO2` is a number, `r1` is a numpy array, so their sum is a numpy array. But `F[0]` is a scalar. What you can do is use `r1[0]` or `sum(r1)` - actual approach depends on your needs.